# Crystal Reports 2008 - Summary of Non-Additive Formula Field

Tags: crystal-reports, formula, crystal-reports-2008, summary

My apologies if this has been answered already; it probably has, but I haven't found it in over an hour of Google and SO searching.

I have a non-additive formula field (`Cost / Qty`).  It works fine on detail rows, but when I add it to my group footers, it returns the values from the last detail row rather than a group-level calculation.  What do I need to do to get the formula evaluated upon all the rows in a group?  I'm surprised this isn't default behavior when adding a field to a group header or footer.

Here's what I'm getting:

```
Category    Cost Qty Avg Cost
Detail A-1  $100   1 $   100
Detail A-2  $200   3 $    67
Footer A    $300   4 $    67
```

I expect to see an Avg Cost of $75 in the footer: $300 / 4.  If I used an aggregate I'd get an incorrect value (e.g., $167 for Sum, $83 for Avg).  In Cognos, I'd use "Expression" as my aggregation formula.

Can some experienced CR user please tell me what I need to do?

Comment: FYI, if I change my formula to "Sum(Cost) / Sum(Qty)", it sums across *all* records, so I get the grand total average repeated on every line, both detail and summary.

Comment: +1 for clarity and trying to find the answer on your own :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a new formula field just for the Report Footer.

So if your detail formula is like this:

`{Test.Cost} / {Test.Qty}`

Then you need to create new formula with the following:

`Sum ({Test.Cost}) / Sum ({Test.Qty})`

and place it in the Report Footer. This will return the correct average ( 300 / 4 = 75 )

**EDIT:**

If you want to do this for a Group Footer a similar principle applies. You have to create a new formula field and add it to the Group Footer.

If you were grouping by the `Category` field for instance then your formula to calculate the average over the group would look like this:

`Sum ({Test.Cost}, {Test.Category}) / Sum ({Test.Qty}, {Test.Category})`

Comment: Sure you need to specify grouping condition in Sum(<field>[,<group>]) expression, otherwise it sums over entire report. Consult CR help for details and syntax :)

Comment: @Arvo - I have updated my answer. I have no provided examples for adding the formula to both the Report Footer & Group Footer. I had quoted Group Footer earlier when in actual fact it was the Report Footer. Thanks

Comment: I agree with your Edited answer. I was about to say the same thing.

Comment: That did it, thanks, Barry!  I created three copies of each non-additive formula, one for details, one for groups, and one for the report, and they work great.  That's nine formulae for one simple report.  I'm thinking of putting "will not work with CR, ever again" on my résumé.  On a more serious note, I do think it says something when it's easier to add totals and subtotals in the SQL source than the reporting tool.